# Irreducibility of polynomials of a certain kind

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Let us look at factorization over the integers of polynomials of the form $x^n+n$. For the first few values of $n$ we get

- $x+1$ - irreducible
- $x^2+2$ - irreducible
- $x^3+3$ - irreducible
- $x^4+4$ - irred- oh, wait, this one can be factored as $(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$
- $x^5+5$ - irreducible

I tested for up to $n=20$ and all of them except for $x^4+4$ are irreducible.

So is there any other $n$ such that the polynomial $x^n+n$ can be factorised? If not, then why did $x^4+4$ break the pattern?

Comment: Your examples of irreducibility for n=2,3,5 follow from Eisenstein's criterion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion).

Comment: There are indeed others. The same idea for $x^4+4$ allows you to produce a factorization for $x^{4k^4}+4k^4$.

Comment: As suggested in Bill's answer, there are even more examples, e.g. $X^{27} + 27 = (X^9)^3 + 3^3$ is divisible by $X^9 + 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are special cases of the following

**Theorem** $\ $ Suppose $\,F\,$ is a field and  $\:a\in F\:$   and $\:0 < n\in\mathbb Z.\ $ Then

$\ \ \ x^n\! - a\, $ is irreducible over $\,F \iff a \not\in F^{\large p}\:$ for all primes $\:p\mid n,\:$ and $\ a\not\in -4\,F^4\,$ if $\: 4\mid n $

A proof can be found in many textbooks, e.g. Karpilovsky, [Topics in Field Theory, Theorem 8.1.6](http://books.google.com/books?id=-2WR0fw9gLMC&pg=PA425&lpg=PA425) or Lang's *Algebra* (section on Galois Theory).